# Mirror bottom overlay designators in Altium

Tags: altium

When I generate a layout documentation in Altium, I want that the outline of the PCB is always the same. E.g. not mirrored when I look at the bottom layer.
But this way the bottom overlay designators are mirrored.
Is it possible to mirror the bottom overlay designators in the pdf generator without manually to have to mirror the designators and move them to the right position afterwards? 
Mirroring them manually has the disadvantage that they have been moved around.

Comment: Do you plan to change them back before generating your gerbers? If you don't they'll be backwards on your actual PCB, which would be quite a bit worse than just being backwards  in the GUI

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to put the board outline on its own layer, and include it, along with the appropriate note layers in the outjob.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be to run the following query in the "PCB Filter":

`IsText And OnBottomSilkscreen`

Finally, in the properties tab, you can toggle the "Mirror" option.

Comment: Yes I tried that already. The problem is that the designators are moved in their position due to the mirroring.

Comment: Consider aligning them from the center. You will only have to move them once, and mirrorring them afterwards should not influence the position.

Comment: Correct, you should set the justification to center-center (up/down and side-side) and then mirror